# Datatables, the "infoEmpty"-message is displayed even though there are records

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

My datatable with ajax source will show the message which is declare in language.infoEmpty even though there are records in the table.

[image]

The function in a class to create the datatable:

```
createTable() {
const self = this;
let table = $('#' + this.getClassName()).DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": this.getUrl() + this.getClassName() + "/ajax-paging",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "name": 'id',
            "targets": [0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false,
        },
        {
            "name": 'Aktiv',
            "targets": [2],
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                if (type === 'display') {
                    let checkedvalue = '';
                    if (data) {
                        checkedvalue = 'checked="checked"';
                    }
                    return '<input style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" type="checkbox" class="form-control form-control_table" ' + checkedvalue + ' disabled>';
                }
                return data;
            },
            "searchable": false,

        },
        {
            "targets": [3],
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                if (type === 'display') {
                    let ret = '<div style="float:right;" aria-label="benutzer actions"><img src="' + self.getUrl() + 'img/bootstrap-icons/search.svg" />';
                    return ret + '</div>';
                }
                return data;
            },
            "searchable": false,
        }
    ],
    "columns": [
        { data: self.idColName, name: "ID" },
        { data: ProjektKonstanten.COL_LOGINNAME, name: "Loginname" },
        { data: ProjektKonstanten.COL_AKTIV, name: "Aktiv" },
        { "orderable": false, data: self.idColName },
    ],
    "order": [1, 'asc'],
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": '_MENU_ records per page'),
        "zeroRecords": 'No match',
        "info": 'Page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_',
        "infoEmpty": 'No user found',
        "infoFiltered": '(filtered from _MAX_ records)',
        "search": 'Search:',
        "paginate": {
            "first": "<img src='" + images.first + "'/>",
            "last": "<img src='" + images.last + "'/>",
            "next": "<img src='" + images.next + "'/>",
            "previous": "<img src='" + images.back + "'/>",
        }
    }
});
return $table;
```

}

Every suggestion/idea is welcome?

(I don't know what else to explain. But Stacktrace tells me that more code is written than explanations, so I am writing this text here so that Stacktrace let me do the post;))

Comment: Some questions: (1) "_...even though there are records in the table_" - How do you know? Can you show us? (2) What is the structure of the JSON response from the Ajax URL? Can you show us that (as JSON text)? (3) How is the HTML table defined? Can you show us the actual HTML?

Comment: (1) see the image. the greyed out is one row.

Thanx for the hint with the JSON response. The maxRowCount and recordFiltered parameter were 0.

Comment: Ah - I see - my mistake. Issue is resolved, now, I assume. You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). That may help future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the JSON response, I saw that maxRowCount and recordFiltered parameters were 0.
After they got the correct number, it worked.